# Get the name of the object based on id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating dynamic drop down menu. Based on the tutorial:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | JSON - Dynamic Dependent Dropdown List using Jquery and Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <h2 align="center">JSON - Dynamic Dependent Dropdown List using Jquery and Ajax</h2><br /><br />
   <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select country</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select state</option>
   </select>
   <br />
   <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_json_data('country');

 function load_json_data(id, parent_id)
 {
  var html_code = '';
  $.getJSON('country_state_city.json', function(data){

   html_code += '<option value="">Select '+id+'</option>';
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    if(id == 'country')
    {
     if(value.parent_id == '0')
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if(value.parent_id == parent_id)
     {
      html_code += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>';
     }
    }
   });
   $('#'+id).html(html_code);
  });

 }

 $(document).on('change', '#country', function(){
  var country_id = $(this).val();
  if(country_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('state', country_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#state').html('<option value="">Select state</option>');
   $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
  }
 });
 $(document).on('change', '#state', function(){
  var state_id = $(this).val();
  if(state_id != '')
  {
   load_json_data('city', state_id);
  }
  else
  {
   $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

User selects country and I want to get the name of the country which was selected. I get correct country id based on this  var country_id = $(this).val(); but I need the name of it. I have tried to get this  name using $("#country_id ").attr("name"); or $(this).attr("name"); but it doesn't work, please help me.

Comment: You have to set the `option` values correctly for that.

Comment: Can you post your generated HTML?  Also, try .text() or $(this).children("option:selected").val()

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me to get what I want: $(this).children("option:selected").text();

Comment: @Gabrielek If you found the answer by yourself, add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected option text by using following code.

```
var country_name = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/tk7fmb1d/3/)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
`$(this).children("option:selected").text();`